# What is the object of "instrui"?

Tags: verbs, accusative

How does one construct a sentence containing "to teach someone something"? Can I have two objects in the accusative or do I need a preposition?

- Ŝi instruas lin la francan.
- Ŝi instruas al li la francan.
- Ŝi instruas lin pri la franca.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using two direct objects with one verb is not recommended; I'm not sure if it's technically ungrammatical, or just strongly unpreferred, but in either case it's best to avoid sentences like *"*Ŝi instruis lin la francan*".

The other two options are both acceptable, and I have seen both used frequently. Either the student or the subject taught can be the object of *instrui*, and the other, if mentioned, is introduced by the suitable preposition, I can *instrui ion al iu* or *instrui iun pri io*. There may be a difference of nuance: if I *instrui al li la francan* that implies that I'm teaching him to speak and understand French, that French is added to his knowledge. Whereas if I *instrui lin pri la franca*, then perhaps I'm just teaching him about its grammar and vocabulary, or perhaps its history and literature, but not necessarily to speak and understand it. (*instrui al li pri la franca* has essentially the same meaning).

If only one object is mentioned, then of course context and feasibility determine the meaning. But of course one can imagine an interchange like "*Mi instruas la anglan.*" "*Bone, la angla ja bezonas ion lerni!*" But obviously that's a joke, not an actual misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8):

You will see it both ways. In most cases, you use *instrui* with *al*:

- *Mi instruos al li la francan.*

However, it is possible for the learner to be the direct object (examples from *Fratoj Grimm* and *La Malnova Testameno*:

- *“Mi konas rimedon, lin instrui timon.”*
- *Instruu knabon konforme al lia vojo*

Cases where the object of *instrui* is a pronoun are very common. Here's just one from *Fundamenta Krestomatio de la Lingvo Esperanto*

- *La pastro instruis lin pri la preĝo*

Similar examples of the form *instrui iun pri* are common throughout the Esperanto literature.

Answer (score 1):

If you're teaching an action, the subject is accusative.

> Mi instruis lin paroli france.

If you're teaching something where the accusative on a noun is appropriate, use *instrui al ~*.

> Ŝi instruis al li la francan.